# Have I used "double" correctly in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice

At first I wrote it as follows:

> The number of houses in 2010 was twice as large as that in 2008.

But then I decided to shorten it like this:

> The number of houses in 2010 was double that in 2008.

Is the second one true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of "double" in this context is good.  Here are some more examples from the wild:

> The report finds that average broadband speeds in the UK now stand at 6.4Mbps, which is more than double that in 2008. [BBC](https://www.bbc.com/news/mobile/technology-11551200)

> Yorkshire Building Society found that 367,038 mortgages were issued to first-time buyers last year. That figure is more than double that in 2008 [Independent](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/business/news/first-time-buyer-level-uk-property-market-research-a8707481.html)